# The convergence of $\sum_1^{+\infty}b_n$ follows from the convergence of $\sum_1^{+\infty}a_n$ given that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to1$.

Tags: analysis

> It is true that if 
>   $$
> \sum_1^{+\infty}a_n\qquad\text{and}\sum_1^{+\infty}b_n
> $$
>   satisfies 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1,
> $$
>   then the convergence of $\sum_1^{+\infty}b_n$ follows from the convergence of $\sum_1^{+\infty}a_n$?

What I know is that if there are both positive series, this claim is true.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30539/81360)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true if the series are not eventually constant sign.

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
converges, yet
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac1k\right)
$$
does not converge.

However,
$$
\frac{\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac1k}{\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}}
=1-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
which tends to $1$.

Comment: +1 You type too fast :)

Comment: The general condition is that the series have  terms with (ultimately) constant sign.

Comment: @Bernard: indeed; most statements about series are true when a condition is true for the tail of the series. I have modified the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) works only for positive $a_n$ and $b_n$ (that is both eventually with constant sign) but it doesn't works in general, for example for the limit case

$$a_n=\frac{1}{ n}$$

$$b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{ \sqrt n}$$

we have

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt n}{n}\to 0 $$

but $a_n$ diverges.